# Is there a way to save dataRow as strings even though some datatypes are different in database

Tags: c#

I am getting data as text from the spreadsheet ,but when i try to save it i get 'Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Double.'

```
  public void TableSaveImportedData(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        string tableName = "Cable";
        using (OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\1Des\\SampleProjects\\SampleProj01\\SampleProj01.MDB"))
        {
            oleDbConnection.Open();
            using (OleDbDataAdapter oleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter())
            {

                using (OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from "+ tableName ,oleDbConnection  ))
                {
                    oleDbDataAdapter.SelectCommand = dbCommand;
                    using (OleDbCommandBuilder oleDbCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(oleDbDataAdapter))
                    {
                        oleDbDataAdapter.InsertCommand = oleDbCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();

                        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                        oleDbDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet ,tableName);
                        oleDbCommandBuilder.RefreshSchema();
                        oleDbDataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
                        dataTable.AcceptChanges();
                        XtraMessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: The error message suggests that the framework did attempt to convert the data but failed, presumably because it wasn't compatible.

Comment: Have you tried simply typecasting before attempting to save?

Comment: Yes ,I tried typecasting and it worked fine thank you!!